# MPI Busy wait for response

Tags: c++, asynchronous, synchronization, mpi, busy-waiting

I had something like

```
while(j<nOSlaves)
        {
            //Iterate through all the slaves.
            for(int i=1;i<nOSlaves && j<nOSlaves;i++)
            {
                //Create a taskMessage which contains length and distance.
                MPI_Status st;
                MPI_Recv(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);

                if (buffer > 0)
                { //Handle the message.... }
            }
        }
```

The problem now is that I have to wait everyone until the message arrives, I wanted it faster and tried it async.

```
MPI_Irecv(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rq);

            int flag = 0;
            MPI_Test(&rq, &flag, &st);

            //If the asynchronous message has been received advance, else try again later.
            if (flag)
            { //Handle the message.... }
```

But after each iteration of the for I will lose the request.
Is there a way to iterate throught all the "slaves" and look if some already answered?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here, what is the bigger communication pattern? Looks like you could to use some sort of collective, but the question is not clear enough to properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

With that error you have some block. Your sends and receives are not happening at the same time.

So `MPI_Irecv` is the non blocking receive function while `MPI_Recv` is a blocking function. Since you do not include your sending functions it is difficult to tell what is causing the blocking here (but given that error message this is likely the case). I suggest looking at [Hristo Ilieve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374437/hristo-iliev)'s (he seems to be active here) [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBgx_S5ougk). One of the hardest things in MPI is the blocking. A way you could ensure that everything is caught up is to make use of `MPI_Barrier` though I mostly use that for debugging. If you are concerned with speed then passing a single integer is not a great idea, unless you are using it for indexing. You can also use `MPI_Scatterv` if you want to have uneven chunks sent out. If you are sending the same section of `buffer`, which it looks like you are, you might try `MPI_Bcast`.

I find that it helps to write down some parts of the code to make sure that they are not blocking each other.